# Using jboss 6.1.0.GA rewrite valve

Tags: jboss, url-rewriting

I am trying to use the RewriteVavle in jboss 6.1.0.GA.

I am trying to ensure that requests to a url like 
`localhost:/foo` get sent to `localhost:/foobar/xyz`.
I have tried adding a context file to the `WEB-INF` directory as explained:

https://simplesassim.wordpress.com/2012/09/02/how-to-rewrite-urls-with-the-rewrite-valve-of-jboss-web-2-1-3/

I tried the suggestions at 
https://developer.jboss.org/thread/234205?start=0&tstart=0 and  https://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/7.0.x/rewrite.html

The contents of my `rewrite.properties` file is:

```
RewriteRule ^/foo/.* /foobar=$1
```

My `context.xml` file is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Context>
        <Valve className="org.jboss.web.rewrite.RewriteValve" />
    </Context>
```

The start of my `jboss-web.xml` file is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <jboss-web>
        <valve>
            <class-name>org.jboss.web.rewrite.RewriteValve</class-name>
        </valve>
        <security-domain flushOnSessionInvalidation="false">other</security-domain>
```

From everything that I have it suggest have jboss is not doing anything different from normal. I have checked the contents of the war file, files such as context.xml and rewrite.properties are present in the war file.
I have unzipped all the jboss jar files and can confirm that the `classorg.jboss.web.rewrite.RewriteValve` is present.

Q. Does the jboss rewrite rule support mapping of a root context application.
Q. Is there any type of loging that can be turned on for the rewrite filter
Q. Is there a better way of doing this type of thing ?  I am trying very hard not to have Apache front end this.

Comment: Thank you for your code edit, my only excuse is that I happen to be dyslexia, so poor grammar can be a curse.